# Is it possible to have a sticky header, scrolling to anchors all in a responsive layout?

Tags: header, responsive-design, anchor, sticky, smooth-scrolling

I have a responsive layout and I am using sticky.js for my header. This seems to be working minus a few glitches that I can live with. But my anchors are always off (I am using smooth scrolling). I am not sure how to compensate for the sticky header when scrolling to an anchor when the responsive layout is constantly changing the width and height?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a whole lot you can do with straight-CSS which won't distort your design.  To tackle this issue in previous projects, I have used jQuery to handle these types of scrolling/anchor issues.

**What You Have Now:** `<a>` tags that look for `id`'s on the page.  The problem is this:  when the site goes responsive, those anchor tags don't line up so nicely with your DOM layout.

**My Solution:**  To give you the high level concept - I used jQuery to modify the ID positions on the fly.  Say you click on a link when the site is full-size, and everything is fine.  jQuery is not needed here.  Now say that when you click that same link when the site was scaled to about the 768px-width range (iPad portrait): then my anchors might look as if they were about 100px off (for example).  I wrote a bit of jQuery to handle this: **"If the width is *_*_, then offset the anchor `ID`'s by ___px."**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JS to account for the difference at time-of-scroll, rather than trying to artificially alter the height property of your anchor tags. Here's a function that might work for you, using pure JS:

```
adjustScroll = function () {
  // Sticky nav selector (you'll have to provide your own selector)
  const nav = document.querySelector('header>nav');

  if (location.href.indexOf("#") >= 0) {
    // Find the name of the anchor
    let n = location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf("#")+1);

    // Find the anchor by name, if it exists
    let a = document.querySelector('a[name="'+n+'"]');
    if (!a) {
      return;
    }

    // Set y value as y-value of the anchor, offset by the header height
    let y = a.offsetTop;
    y -= nav.height + 10;

    // Scroll to the y position
    window.scrollTo(0, y);
  }
}

// Call it wherever you need to call it
adjustScroll();
```

Examples of where to call it might be on a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, or on an [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event for anchor tags.